# How to store solution path in the registry

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, registry

I'm working on a large solution; for testing purposes I want to store the solution path under a certain build configuration (i.e. Debug).

I want help to use the pre-build event command line to store $(SolutionDir) in the windows registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write to the registry from the command line in a build step, you could write the key to a .reg file, then run regedit and import the file.

There's a guide [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516).

You can use $(SolutionPath) macro in Visual Studio in your pre-build command line when building the .reg file.

Experiment using a batch file, and once it's working, you can move the code into your build step.

Comment: If you decide to use a batch file, you can pass it as an argument. Batch files can take arguments. See documentation here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true